# Xamarin Shell Flyout created from database data

Tags: shell, xamarin, flyout

I have app of lists and items in each list. The list and their items are stored in two tables. A list data would be like "Grocery" and the list items like "bananas" etc. You can add lists and items in the app. Right now I have a list content page that lists the list names. Tap one and you go to a content page of the items in that list. This works, but I want to populate the Shell flyout with the list names from a database query in the AppShell.xaml.cs file. I want to do something like this:

```
                ShellSection shell_section = new ShellSection();

                var lists = await SLOMBListDataStore.GetSLOMBListsAsync(true);
                foreach (var list in lists)
                {
                    shell_section.Title = list.ListName;
                    shell_section.Icon = "tab_feed.png";
                    shell_section.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new SLOMBListDataPage(new SLOMBListDataViewModel(list.id)) });
                    this.Items.Add(shell_section);
                }

                BindingContext = this;
```

This, by the way, does not work. Creating the entries works manually if I use shell_section1, shell_section2 etc, but then you have to hard code the lists. Is it possible to do what I want, create the flyout from the query data? Thanks

Comment: you are using the same ShellSection every time.  You need to create it *inside* the loop, not *outside*

Comment: I would have to destroy the object each loop. I am not sure how to do that. Google says calling the garbage collector is a bad idea. I was hoping that when I added it to Items I could reuse it.

Comment: Why would you do that?  You are still using it in your Items collection.  Just move it inside the loop.

Comment: Well, I am embarrassed now. I still have issues with the getting the database to work right, but when I ginned up a list of demo objects everything worked just fine. Thank you for your quick response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the initialization code into the for loop like:

```
var lists = await SLOMBListDataStore.GetSLOMBListsAsync(true);
foreach (var list in lists)
{
    ShellSection shell_section = new ShellSection();

    shell_section.Title = list.ListName;
    shell_section.Icon = "tab_feed.png";
    shell_section.Items.Add(new ShellContent() { Content = new SLOMBListDataPage(new SLOMBListDataViewModel(list.id)) });
    this.Items.Add(shell_section);
}
```

You need a new instance for each record.

Comment: This is what Jason said in the comment above. It is the answer. Everything works fine now. Thanks